# How to get real-time subprocess output?

Tags: python, html, linux, flask

I'm trying to call the command "tail - f" on the server to be displayed in real time in this html page. In this case no success, only simple output commands, instant cast. How do I use subprocess in the flask to real-time command output?

**app.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
from flask import Flask, render_template,request,


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route( "/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fist():
    with Popen(['tail-f','/var/log/syslog'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE) as a:
        out,err = a.communicate()
    data0 = out.decode('utf-8')     
    return render_template('page.html',data0=data0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .exit_data{
                overflow: hidden;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Page TEST</title>
        <body>
            <div>
                <h2>TEST OUTPUT</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="exit_data">
                {{data0}}
            </div>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use websocket and continue push the content of the output stream to the browser.